# 555 as slow PWM driver

Tags: pwm, timer, 555

I would like a slow PWM output, driving a relay turning an AC heating element on and off.
I desire a period time of around 10s.

What is a realistic upper period time limit for a PWM circuit like the one found [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-and-dirty-Pulse-Width-Modulation-PWM-Wi/)?

According to EveryCircuit, a 100 kOhm potentiometer and 100 uF C1 capacitor should leave me with my desired ~10s period time, but I suspect noise could become an issue with resistances so large and period times so slow.

Comment: Are you running this open-loop? (Are you just manually set the PWM duty cycle and have no electronic feedback used to adjust the duty cycle based upon readings of some process variable under control?)

Comment: I'm not sure why you think noise would be an issue. One of my very first electronic projects ever was a 1-hour 555-based timer that used something like 1000 uF and 3.3 M -- well outside the recommended limits, but it still worked fine for many years.

Comment: @jonk Yes, open cycle it is. I would just put some trial-and-error scale on the potentiometer - doesn't need to be precise / repeatable.

Comment: 10s has definitely been done, but I'll be honest and do whatever I do whenever someone asks about the 555 in a PWM application: Chances are, considering cost of passives, a cheap microcontroller would do just as well but be way more flexible. In this case, any cheap microcontroller hooked up to some kind of analog or digital thermometer would, in the next stage of development, allow for a 10 line addition of source code to convert this to a PID controller – which would, in a *very* rough analogy, be the equivalent to a trial and error scale, only that the controller does the trying and

Comment: "homing in" on the desired temperature, instead of you sitting in front of whatever you're heating and turning the nob, waiting, checking, making a mark on the scale, turning, waiting…

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yeah if precision is needed the  microcontroller is probably better, but the 555 circuit needs fewer parts (it can drive the relay directly from the discharge out out pin) , and is probably cheaper if an an electrolytic capacitor can be used fro the timing part.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm aware of that, and using one of the 328p's I have flying around would be an option as well. I do believe I won't need actual temperature markings, and that markings of "100%" - "90%" etc. would suffice. The project needs to be low-cost however, so I thought I'd look into using a 555 on a stripboard for once rather than having a PCB made.

Comment: @TobiasWeiß certainly, Atmegas are more expensive :) But not every microcontroller is an Atmega! For your purposes, an Attiny5 (USD0.72 incl. free shipping from [reputable sources](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/attiny5-tshr/microchip-technology)) would suffice massively, and you'd need a single external [self-biased transistor](https://www.arrow.com/en/products/2sc3912-tb-e/on-semiconductor) (around 4ct) to drive the relay. Then, add a decoupling cap(100 nF would be more than enough,4ct?)to stabilize the MCU's supply voltage. That's definitely fewer components than your 555 design needs :)

Comment: Yep, that's an SMD package on the Attiny and transistor, but it's benign ones, which you can directly solder onto wires and glue e.g. to relay bottoms. The reduced voltage and power requirements of the MCU compared to a 555 might allow for a cheaper (because lying around) power supply, e.g. based on 1990's era cellphone chargers or even batteries (but if you go for batteries, you'd probably want to replace the relay by a semiconductor – in fact, you could build a thyristor dimmer, if your heater is just a resistive load).

Answer (score 1):

With tantalum electrolytic capacitors you can choose ones with ultra low leakage @ Vmax equiv to  1M to 10M +.

But it is far better to use a Triac and temp sensor and driver to triac  with hysteresis that controls the drift temp. about any setpoint or use phase control for linear PWM control with some gain. to reduce the error or PID loop for ultra fine control. (<<1'C)

Comment: +1 for suggesting a tantalum capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

At 100uF that's either a very large film capacitor or it's an electrolytic capacitor, the latter mar vary in capacitance significantly with temperature,

100K should be fine, so long as the wires to the 555 are short, even 1 meg would work here.

The analogue inputs are connected to the timing capacitor so they won't see much noise.

The capacitor on pin 5 (control voltage) significantly reduces noise succeptability By filtering the other internal comparator inputs

Supply ripple is not an issue so long as it's less than about 25%

Answer (score 0):

I second the microcontroller approach. Attiny10 is less than a 555, support components would be less too.  Gives you flexibility if you want to change the time in the future without having to remove & replace components.